# What is the rational behind the chosen /sites styling info?

Tags: support, style

I was wondering why the chosen styling data is provided though the API.  It makes sense to provide it, but I feel like we are only getting part of the information.

```
"styling": {
    "link_color": {
      "description": "color of links, as a CSS style color value",
      "values": "string",
      "optional": false
    },
    "tag_foreground_color": {
      "description": "foreground color of tags, as a CSS style color value",
      "values": "string",
      "optional": false
    },
    "tag_background_color": {
      "description": "background/fill color of tags, as a CSS style color value",
      "values": "string",
      "optional": false
    }
}
```

It seems to me that we should be provided with stuff like background color, accepted answer color, no answer color, border styles, etc.  Or, why provide any style information at all?

Comment: Well, remember the rules: "Don't copy the look and feel..." so the more color info they provide, the more it will look like the real thing.

Comment: @George Right, but why do they provide any info at all then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature came about after some internal discussion.

The gist of it was, what's the bare minimum you need to make a *question link* look like it belongs to a given site?  `link_color`, `tag_foreground_color`, and `tag_background_color` are what came out of that discussion.

The reason for restricting to just that subset of a site is that, as George Edison pointed out, we don't want people copying the look and feel of a site wholesale.

Comment: So, you decided that this was enough info to determine the site a link belongs to?  Where do tags fit into that?

Comment: @jjnguy - we assumed the common case when linking a question would be to display its title (`link_color`) and the tags on it (`tag_foreground_color` and `tag_background_color`).

Comment: ...and this is not considered copying the look and feel?

Comment: @George - using the colors the API provides to style question links and tags is A-OK.

Comment: Great! I just switched all my stuff to 1.0 when I saw that my stuff stopped responding.